# List of syntax highlighting keywords xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am trying to find a list of the keywords that Xcode uses to highlight code while editing. I was able to find the themes location (/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FontAndColorThemes/), but I can't seem to be able to find the list. Does anyone know where it's located?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching, I found it: It's located at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources
```